# Use MongoDB $slice operator on an array within an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, slice

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
> db.test.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "1:1419552000",
    "l0" : [
        {
            "l1" : [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "l1" : [
                "11",
                "12",
                "13",
                "14"
            ]
        },
        {
            "l1" : [
                "21",
                "22",
                "23",
                "24"
            ]
        },
        {
            "l1" : [
                "31",
                "32",
                "33",
                "34"
            ]
        },
        {
            "l1" : [
                "41",
                "42",
                "43",
                "44"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to be able to fetch a range of elements from within any of the arrays at level 1 (l1). But the $slice operator doesn't to be able to do that. Is this not possible at all?

```
> db.test.findOne({}, {"l0" : {$slice: 1}})
{
    "_id" : "1:1419552000",
    "l0" : [
        {
            "l1" : [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

> db.test.findOne({}, {"l0.0.l1" : {$slice: 2}})
{
    "_id" : "1:1419552000",
    "l0" : [
...
returns the entire object
...
}
```

Any pointers or help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that, for my incorrect query:
`db.test.findOne({}, {"l0.0.l1" : {$slice: 2}})` it should be:
`{ "_id" : "1:1419552000", "l0" : [ "2", "1" ] }` or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework with [**`$skip`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/), [**`$limit`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to get to the subarray range you need:

```js
db.test.aggregate(
    {
        $match: { _id: "1:1419552000" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$l0"
    },
    {
        $limit: 1 // keeps the first element in l0
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$l0.l1"
    },
    {
        $limit: 2 // keeps the first two elements in the first l1
    },
    {
        $group: // groups the unwound elements back into an array
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            l0: { $addToSet: "$l0.l1" }
        }
    }
)
```

This will be returned:

```js
{ "_id" : "1:1419552000", "l0" : [ "2", "1" ] }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the required output in your question. Assuming you only want to return elements of `l1` that meet a certain range criteria (e.g >41) you could use the `$unwind` parameter and the `aggregate` function:

```
 db.test.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$l0"
}, {
    $unwind: "$l0.l1"
}, {
    $match: {
        "l0.l1": {
            $gt: "41"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "l1": {
            "$addToSet": "$l0.l1"
        }
    }
})
```

This will return:

```
{
   "_id": "1:1419552000",
    "l1": ["43", "44", "42"]
}
```

If you add the required output to your question, I can modify the query to return the correct output.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Sorry about not adding the expected output in the question. Added it as a comment now. Accepting another answer as it, IMO, explains things better. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

For the sample document you provided, `db.test.findOne({}, {"l0.l1" : {$slice: 2}})` returns

```
{
    "_id" : "1:1419552000",
    "l0" : [
        {
            "l1" : [
                "1",
                "2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "l1" : [
                "11",
                "12"
            ]
        }, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, this is not what I had in mind. I just updated the question with the expected output in comments.